# Видимость микроразметки shema.org

Tags: seo

подскажите, в микроразметки shema есть обязательные поля, к примеру price, но мне он на странице не нужен, а для валидности shema обязателен, можно ли таким полям присваивать style="display:none"??? Не будет ли это проблемой для отображения в выдачи или сео

Comment: Например: `<meta itemprop="price" content="888.80" />`. Но тогда к чему такая разметка с ложной информацией?

Comment: это прямо в тегах боди можно писать?

Comment: Там данные будут не ложные а очень даже актуальные, но мне их вывод на странице не нужен просто, а без них код валидацию у гугла не проходит.

Comment: Размещайте внутри тега описываемой сущности, который имеет атрибут `itemtype`, например: `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"><meta itemprop="price" content="888.80" /> ... остальная разметка ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> можно ли таким полям присваивать style="display:none"???

Не делайте это, потому что для **[Гугл это есть сигнал спама в структурированных данных](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175?hl=ru)**, такой как:

> ***С помощью структурированных данных размечен скрытый контент***
>
> Структурированные данные обнаружены в элементах, которые не видны
>   пользователям.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. важная информация=)